# MS Access Convert text to shortdate

Tags: ms-access

Hi all i have a question,

I have a field in the table whereby its a text field and i want to convert it to date field. Though all the values within are in date format however its not convenient to change because of some circumstances.

Thus i need to change the text field to date field so as to do a comparison or validation.

Im using MS access SQL for this project so please help me

I have tried

```
TRANSFORM Count(Registrants.[Field1]) AS CountOfField1
SELECT Registrants.[Country] , Count(Registrants.[Field1]) AS [Total Of Field1]
FROM Registrants
WHERE Cast(Registrants.Field1 As Date) Between #15/6/2014# AND # 30/8/2014#
GROUP BY Registrants.[Country]
PIVOT Format([Field1]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Cast` does not exist in MS Access sql.

Use `DateValue` instead :

```
WHERE DateValue(Registrants.Field1) Between #15/6/2014# AND #30/8/2014#
```

See [here](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/date/datevalue.php) for sample usage and syntax.

Also I noted a space in your 2nd date, I assume that's a typo.